# Creating a CustomType in ng-admin fails silently

Tags: angularjs, custom-type, ng-admin

I'm trying to write a custom type to create a cascading dropdown.
I start with defining a new custom type extending reference type.
The problem is that no matter what I write inside the class body the component doesn't show up with no error.
Here is the new field class:

```
import ReferenceField from "admin-config/lib/Field/ReferenceField";

class CascadeParentField extends ReferenceField {
 constructor(name) {
        super(name);
        this._type = 'cascade_parent';
        this._cascadeReference = null;
    } 
}
export default CascadeParentField;
```

and the paired FieldView class:

```
export default {
    getReadWidget:   () => '<ma-reference-column field="::field" value="::value" datastore="::datastore"></ma-reference-column>',
    getLinkWidget:   () => '<ma-reference-link-column entry="::entry" field="::field" value="::value" datastore="::datastore"></ma-reference-link-column>',
    getFilterWidget: () => '<ma-reference-field field="::field" value="value" datastore="::datastore"></ma-reference-field>',
    getWriteWidget:  () => '<ma-reference-field field="::field" value="value" datastore="::datastore"></ma-reference-field>'
};
```

While in main.js:

```
myApp.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider', 'FieldViewConfigurationProvider', function(nga, fvp) {
    nga.registerFieldType('cascade_parent', require('./types/CascadeParentField'));
    fvp.registerFieldView('cascade_parent', require('./types/CascadeParentFieldView'));
}]);
```

Any idea? I tried to debug but didn't find any issue...

Answer (score 0):

The nga.registerFieldType using a require will probably generate an exception that 'CascadeParentField' is not a constructor, so you should instead do an import:

```
import CascadeParentField from './types/CascadeParentField.js';
...
myApp.config(['NgAdminConfigurationProvider', 'FieldViewConfigurationProvider', function (nga, fvp) {
nga.registerFieldType('cascade_parent', AmountType);
...
}
```

Besides that, my guess is that documentation is currently broken since that is not stated there but I found it in another SO post:

[ng-admin does not recognize custom field view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508384/ng-admin-does-not-recognize-custom-field-view)

And by the way I have the same issue (not being able to do a custom field view).